# Finding the duplicates, average them and create a proper table

Tags: r

Let's start with my data:

```
> dput(head(tbl_end))
structure(list(`Gene name` = c("at1g01050.1", "at1g01080.1", 
"at1g01090.1", "at1g01220.1", "at1g01320.2", "at1g01420.1"), 
    `1_1` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1_2` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `1_3` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1_4` = c(0, 0.660693687777888, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), `1_5` = c(0, 0.521435654491704, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
    `1_6` = c(0, 0.437291194705566, 0, 0, 0, 1), `1_7` = c(0, 
    0.52204783488213, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1_8` = c(0, 0.524298383907171, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), `1_9` = c(1, 0.376865096972469, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    `1_10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1_11` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ), `1_12` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1_13` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), `1_14` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1_15` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), `1_16` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1_17` = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `1_18` = c(0, 0, 0.476101907006443, 0, 0, 0), `1_19` = c(0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0), `1_20` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1_21` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `1_22` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1_23` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1_24` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Gene name", 
"1_1", "1_2", "1_3", "1_4", "1_5", "1_6", "1_7", "1_8", "1_9", 
"1_10", "1_11", "1_12", "1_13", "1_14", "1_15", "1_16", "1_17", 
"1_18", "1_19", "1_20", "1_21", "1_22", "1_23", "1_24"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

so I have more than 2k rows. As a name of the row I set the gene name but there is a problem. Sometimes same gene has a different "models" (so they put the dot after name and the number 1 or 2) but still it's the same gene so I want to find all of those duplicates (same gene name) and average the values in different columns for this gene and just leave the 1 row with the averaged values.

Is it possible to do ?

Just showing some of the gene names I have:

```
> dput(vec_names)
c("at1g01050.1", "at1g01080.1", "at1g01090.1", "at1g01220.1", 
"at1g01320.2", "at1g01420.1", "at1g01470.1", "at1g01800.1", "at1g01910.5", 
"at1g01920.2", "at1g01960.1", "at1g01980.1", "at1g02020.2", "at1g02100.2", 
"at1g02130.1", "at1g02140.1", "at1g02150.1", "at1g02305.1", "at1g02500.2", 
"at1g02560.1", "at1g02780.1", "at1g02880.3", "at1g02920.1", "at1g02930.2", 
"at1g03030.1", "at1g03090.2", "at1g03110.1", "at1g03130.1", "at1g03210.1", 
"at1g03220.1", "at1g03230.1", "at1g03310.2", "at1g03330.1", "at1g03475.1", 
"at1g03630.2", "at1g03680.1", "at1g03870.1", "at1g03900.1", "at1g04080.2", 
"at1g04130.1", "at1g04170.1", "at1g04190.1", "at1g04270.2", "at1g04350.1", 
"at1g04410.1", "at1g04420.1", "at1g04530.1", "at1g04640.2", "at1g04690.1", 
"at1g04750.2", "at1g04810.1", "at1g04850.1", "at1g04870.2", "at1g05010.1", 
"at1g05180.1", "at1g05190.1", "at1g05320.3", "at1g05350.1", "at1g05520.1", 
"at1g05560.1", "at1g05620.2", "at1g06000.1", "at1g06110.1", "at1g06130.2", 
"at1g06290.1", "at1g06410.1", "at1g06550.1", "at1g06560.1", "at1g06570.1",
```

I think there is a function for that but can't find it.

Comment: take a look at `gsub`, or `str_extract` from the `stringr` package, and `aggregate` ...

Comment: That's definitely what I am looking for but have you any idea how I can mark a duplicates as a pattern which I am looking for ? In an effcient way because I know how I can find them one by one and replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(dat)
dt[, gene_unique := gsub("[.]*", "", dt$Gene)]
cols <- colnames(dt)[2:25]
dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = gene_unique, .SDcols = cols]
```

Using `aggregate` as suggested in comments

```
dat$`Gene name` = gsub("[.]*", "", dat$Gene)
aggregate(. ~ `Gene name`, dat, mean)
```

Comment: That looks ok but after using that function I see the same number of rows as in a previous data I suppose that mean of the duplicates should be taken and stored in 1 row and the rest should be deleted.

Comment: Are you using for all of your data or just the example? There are no duplicates in the example. Add the following line of code right after line 2 above `dt = rbind(dt[1], dt)` and you should see that it will reduce the number of rows from 7 to 6.

Comment: I used it for my data. That should work so it might mean that are no duplicates in my data... which shouldn't be truth. Any fast idea how to check if in my data are any duplicates ?

Comment: Do something like `length(unique(gsub("[.]*", "", vec_names)))`
and `length(vec_names)` and compare the two. I don't see any duplicates in the vec_names that you provided even though the numbering (.2, .5, etc.) suggests that there are.

Comment: `> length(unique(gsub("[.]*", "", vec_names)))
[1] 2744
> length(vec_names)
[1] 2744` so that was stupid question. Now I have to figure out why there are no duplicates. Thanks for that. I will for sure use that function!